# Unity c# -> rotate bone to target Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I want manipulate theBone so it can comes back to InitialRotation after manipulation done, this is my codes

```
void toInitialRotation(Transform theBone, Quaternion theInitialRotation)
{
    //bone.rotation = initialRotation;  //this work but move instantly not animated
    
    var step = 20 * Time.deltaTime; // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.

    // Rotate our transform a step closer to the target's.
    theBone.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(bone.rotation, theInitialRotation, step); //it's work and animated well
}
```

codes above works fine and animated well, but it work based on step, my question is How to make it work based on time, for example if the given time is 3 second then theBone.Rotation  must reach theInitialRotation at 3 second and stop there.
thanks for your help

Comment: If [derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64969025/1092820) helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give them some reputation points as well as help future visitors with a similar question find it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [`Quaternion.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) like e.g.

```
IEnumerator toInitialRotation(Transform theBone, Quaternion targetRotation, float duration)
{
    // If there is no duration immediately jump to the target rotation and terminate the routine
    if(time <= 0)
    {
        theBone.rotation = targetRotation;
        yield break;
    }

    var currentRotation = theBone.rotation;
    
    var timePassed = 0f;  
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        // Will move from 0 to 1
        var factor = timePassed / duration;

        // Interpolates from the current to the target rotation
        theBone.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, factor);

        // Increase by the time passed since last frame
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        // Tells Unity to "pause" the routine, render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // Just to be sure set the rotation fix when done
    theBone.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

And invoke it like

```
StartCoroutine(toInitialRotation(bone, initialRotation, 3f);
```